# I couldn't draw fully gradient background on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I drew gradient background layer on UICollectionView with following code.

```
CAGradientLayer* collectionRadient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
collectionRadient.bounds = self.collectionView.bounds;
collectionRadient.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
collectionRadient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColor CGColor],(id)[endColor CGColor], nil];
UIView* vv = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.collectionView.backgroundView = vv;
[self.collectionView.backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:collectionRadient atIndex:0];
```

It works on iPhone simulator. but not iPad.
Below Image is that. the background layer is taking up only a part of UICollectionView.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a subclass of UIView named GradientView or something similar which you would use as your background view.

In your implementation of GradientView you just need to overload the following class method:

```
+ (Class)layerClass 
{
    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}
```

Then, change your code above to the following:

```
UIView* backgroundView = [[GradientView alloc] initWithFrame:self.collectionView.bounds];
backgroundView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
self.collectionView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
CAGradientLayer* collectionGradient = (CAGradientLayer *)backgroundView.layer;
collectionGradient.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
collectionGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColor CGColor],(id)    [endColor CGColor], nil];
```

I'm hoping that your custom GradientView's layer will automatically resize. If not, you may need to implement the layoutSubviews method in your custom GradientView to resize your gradient layer.

Comment: Another note: I have seen some banding issues in the past when using CAGradientLayer. If this doesn't work, you could consider implementing drawRect in your GradientView subclass to draw a gradient using Core Graphics.

Comment: Thank you for responding. It works very well. 
One more thing, I got warning message that "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CAGradientLayer *__strong' with an expression of type 'CALayer *'". Should it be casted to CAGradient explicitily?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to cast the layer to CAGradientLayer. Otherwise you could add a read only property of type CAGradientLayer that just returns a cast of the view's layer so that users of that class don't need to assume the layer is a gradient layer.